# deleting duplicates from a sorted vector

Tags: c++

[26. Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/)

> Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that
> each element appear only once and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
> modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Given `nums = [1,1,2]`,
>
> Your function should return length = 2, with the first two elements of
> nums being 1 and 2 respectively.
>
> It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length. Example
> 2:
>
> Given `nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4],
>
> Your function should return length = 5, with the first five elements
> of nums being modified to 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively.
>
> It doesn't matter what values are set beyond the returned length.
> Clarification:
>
> Confused why the returned value is an integer but your answer is an
> array?
>
> Note that the input array is passed in by reference, which means
> modification to the input array will be known to the caller as well.
>
> Internally you can think of this:
>
> ```
> // nums is passed in by
> reference. (i.e., without making a copy) int len =
> removeDuplicates(nums);
>
> // any modification to nums in your function would be known by the
> caller. // using the length returned by your function, it prints the
> first len elements. for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
>     print(nums[i]); }
> ```

i am getting this runtime error while submitting it on leetcode it works fine on coding blocks but shows this error in leetcode compilor

Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:9

```
class Solution {
public:
    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
        int k=nums[0];
        for(auto i=nums.begin()+1;i<nums.end();i++)
        {
            if(*i==k) nums.erase(i) , i--;
            else k=*i;
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
```

Can anybody help me in finding the cause of error?

Comment: `nums.erase(i) , i--` -> `i = nums.erase(i)`

Comment: You could just call `sort` and then `unique` for this. (and `erase`).

Comment: Unless you want to do that explicitly for some reason, why don't you do `nums.erase(std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()))`?

Comment: @Emma But [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) will only remove duplicates from consecutive positions unless the sequence is sorted. Even the example in linked page illustrates that.

Comment: If you take a look at [std::vector<T,Allocator>::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) you can see that it `invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase`. So when you do `nums.erase(i)`, the `i` is not valid anymore after that point.

Comment: @TanveerBadar in the context of that question `deleting duplicates from a sorted vector` the `sort` for the `unique` is indeed not required. I guess that's what the comment of Emma might be about. I mean otherwise, the `sort` would also be required for the algorithm of the OP.

Comment: @OP, This is why algorithm functions such as `std::unique` exists, so that you are not writing code that either has bugs, or is inefficient.  Your attempt has both bugs and is inefficient.  The bugs were pointed out by others, but the inefficiency is there because you are calling `erase` every time you find a duplicate, causing the items to be shifted down each time -- what if there are a million duplicates?.  There are better ways of doing this, such as simply overwriting the duplicated item with the next entry.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i just wanted to know what causes the run time error in my code.

Comment: @ShubhSingh The cause is that your code had bugs.  If you access an invalidated iterator the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: @OP, please note that `nums.erase(std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()))` would have also worked on an empty vector.

Comment: @Emma it worked!! thank you.

Comment: @ShubhSingh `return static_cast<int>(std::distance(nums.begin(), std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end())));` -- A one line solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Your code works just fine, missing one edge case (an empty `nums`):

```
            if (nums.empty()) {
                return 0;
            }
```

- Updated Code:

```
class Solution {
    public:
        int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
            if (nums.empty()) {
                return 0;
            }

            int k = nums[0];

            for (auto i = nums.begin() + 1; i < nums.end(); i++) {
                if (*i == k) {
                    nums.erase(i) , i--;
                }

                else {
                    k = *i;
                }
            }

            return nums.size();
        }
};
```

- Maybe we could just write a simple loop using `size()`. This'd pass on LeetCode:

```
// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;

#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

// Start
static const struct Solution {
    using SizeType = std::uint_fast16_t;
    static const int removeDuplicates(
        std::vector<int>& nums
    ) {
        const SizeType len = std::size(nums);
        SizeType count = 0;

        for (SizeType i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
            if (nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) {
                ++count;

            } else {
                nums[i - count] = nums[i];
            }
        }

        return len - count;
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't know about passing on leetcode, but this doesn't *delete* anything.

Comment: Well, that's just ... I think there should be a tag for `leetcode` or competitive programming questions, so that people don't waste time on answering questions that are not really about programming at all :( Only for people who don't want to, of course. It's a perfectly reasonable thing for people to do if they like that sort of thing.

Comment: Huh, really? Is there a meta post or something that you can link to about this? I feel a strong case could be made for a tag of this nature.

Comment: @cigien here the "problem" is just that the quesitons title does not match with the actual requirements (actually only the size of the container after removing elements is needed, something you can get even without the container), but in general I completely agree

Comment: Regarding the `leetcode` tag or `competitive-coding` in general [We need to de-leet leetcode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399117/we-need-to-de-leet-leetcode) @TanveerBadar